# Mongoose populate method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having the most awful trouble trying to get the populate feature in mongoose to work. I have looked at all the threads here on SO and nothing has helped. My schema is mapped out below.

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/**
 * Prodcut Feature Extra
 */
var extra = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Product name',
    trim: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  toolTip: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 140
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

/**
 * Product Feature Schema
 */
var feature = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill feature name',
    trim: true
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

/**
 * Product Schema
 */
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Product name',
    trim: true
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  features: [feature],
  extras: [extra],
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Feature', feature);
mongoose.model('Extra', extra);
mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

I have tried all of the following queries in a Mongoose Repl but nothing works

```js
 models.Product.find().populate("Extra", "name").exec()
 models.Product.find().populate({path: "extras", location: "Extra"}).exec()
 models.Product.find().populate('extras', 'name').exec()
 models.Product.find().populate('extras', 'Extra').exec()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? This is killing me!!

Comment: Please show what "but nothing works" means. Is there an error?

Comment: Not sure what version of Mongoose you are on, but I've never seen Schema.ObjectId as a valid type. That should read "Schema.Types.ObjectId" - that should be causing a schema validation error at the least...

Comment: what do you want to achieve? In your schema `extras` is not a reference, but an embedded document, it is not supposed to work like that. Please explain what you really want, then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious!

This initialization below, isn't has to be done before referencing in ProductSchema?

```
mongoose.model('Feature', feature);
mongoose.model('Extra', extra);
```

Something like this

```
mongoose.model('Feature', feature);
mongoose.model('Extra', extra);

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
name: {
 type: String,
 default: '',
 required: 'Please fill Product name',
 trim: true
},
created: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
},
features: [ {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Feature'
}],
extras: [ {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Extra'
}],
user: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
}
});
```

Than this should work

```
models.Product.find().populate("extras")
```